# How to save language selected of the application in sharedpreferences android

Tags: android

I am a new application developer. How to make the language of choice from user to save so that will be not to lose after restarting the application.sorry to ask the question again, but I tried to work on our previous posts and didn't work with me.

my code:

```
public class Arabic extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.arabic);

        findViewById(R.id.BTN_ar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                setLocale("ar");
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.BTN_en).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setLocale("en");
            }
        });

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Arabic.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });


        

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Arabic.class);
        startActivity(refresh);


    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences,

When the language button is clicked, you can add the language as such:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("LOCALE", lang);
editor.commit();
```

To make sure the changes are applied when you restart your app, you can override the Application class and set the locale there, retrieving it as:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String locale = sharedPref.getString("LOCALE", defaultValue);
```

This is of course a simple way to do this, ideally, you should have a class for storing all your shared preferences.

You can find more info on [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java) and [changing the locale](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/25011/change-locale-of-android-application-programatically#:%7E:text=Android%20Change%20locale%20of%20android%20application%20programatically&text=In%20order%20to%20change%20Application,can%20use%20below%20locale%20util.&text=Initialize%20locale%20that%20user%20preferred%2C%20from%20Application%20class.&text=Note%20%3A%20Always%20initialize%20locale%20in,can%20use%20LocalizationActivity%20as%20follow.).

Comment: Hello brother, thank you for your answer. I applied what you mentioned but I faced one problem. The question has been updated, please see the image

Comment: now this problem come : Cannot resolve symbol 'defaultValue'

Comment: That would be the default value you want for your locale, so for eg put "en" instead

Comment: Hi brother if you can see here Please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901835/how-can-stop-refresh-activity-android