# How can stop refresh activity android

Tags: android

I am a new application developer.I try to make user can choose his preferred language and save it in SharedPreferences.Now the code is work but the problem when app start the activity refresh it is updated non-stop.
Sorry to ask the question again, but I tried to work on our previous posts and didn't work with me.

example: When this activity turned on, it opens and closes every time without stop . but If I delete this method get(); from onCreate it's work fine.

my code :

```
public class Arabic extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.arabic);
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("mykedy",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        findViewById(R.id.BTN_ar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                setLocale("ar");
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.BTN_en).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setLocale("en");
            }
        });

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Arabic.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

       //

        get();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setLocale(String lang) {

        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
       Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Arabic.class);
      startActivity(refresh);
        SharedPreferences share = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = share.edit();
        edit.putString("LOCALE",lang);
        edit.commit();



    }
    public void get( ) {
        SharedPreferences share = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       String lan = (share.getString("LOCALE",""));
       setLocale(lan);

    }

}
```

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by it keeps refreshning without stop ?

Comment: When this activity turned on, it opens and closes every time without stop . but If I delete this method get(); from onCreate it's work fine @takieddine

Comment: You should keep get and setLocale in your Application class

Comment: I didn't understand very well my brother, can you solve the question? @kiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the get( ) method you called setLocale() and in the setLocale you are refreshing the activity without finishing  `finish()`  , so each time you call setLocale or get() the activity will refresh.

What you can do  is to refresh the activity only when the user change the language like this :

```
findViewById(R.id.BTN_ar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                setLocale("ar");
               //the correct way to refresh an activity
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
               
            }
        });
```

And remove this from setLocale() :

```
 Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Arabic.class);
 startActivity(refresh);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens in your Activity:

1. when the Activity starts, onCreate() is called
2. in onCreate() you call get()
3. in get() you call setLocale()
4. in setLocale() you restart the Activity with these two lines:

```
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Arabic.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
```

5. when the Activity is restarted, the loop begins again from 1.

If you remove the get() call from the onCreate() method, it breaks the loop. That's why it's working fine in this case.

Can you remove the lines that restart the activity from the setLocale() method or does that break something else in your Activity?